# Recommendations for database schema/data structure for picking default value given a list

Tags: sql, database, design-patterns, data-structures, database-design

Sorry for the vague title.

We have a use case where we can get 0 to many roles and from that list we need to set a "default value"

For instance say we scan the text of a document (doc 1) for roles, and we find role x, y , z and another document (doc b) we find roles a, b , y. And a third document (doc 2) we find role y.

We have a business rule that says if we find roles x, y, z all together choose z.

- If we find x, z together return no default.
- If we find a, choose a, regardless of what other roles are with it.
- And if we find just one role, default to that role.

If the rules were hard and fast I could easily just make this as a giant switch statement, or something in code, but things can change on the fly so I would like to store this in a database or something that so that I can just do something along the lines of:

```
PseudoSelectDefault(Inputs[])
  If inputs.length == 0
    Return ""
  Else of inputs.length == 1
    Return inputs[0]
  Else 
   Return RunSomeSql(Inputs)
   // Where RunSomeSql chooses the default for me.
```

But I'm at a loss for how this database Should be structured.

I'm assuming this isn't a new problem but I'm not sure what sort of key words I should be looking for.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

We ended up changing the route on this a bit.
I should have specified originally the list of roles he have is near a hundred or so items long. and coming up with every single possible combination would be a pain.

What we ended up doing was assigning every role a default priority on a scale of 1-10 (or some arbitrary length, could be 0-1 and use doubles or whatever). then when we find the list of roles in a document we lookup the priority of each role in our database, and just default the role with the highest value. or if there is a tie, flag for manual intervention, record the relevant meta data for the roles found, and user selected role, and over time adjust the priority or roles as needed. This way we didn't have to maintain a list of every possible combination we may come across.

I realize that the solution for this varies a bit from the original question, and for that I apologize.

Comment: One way to reduce this problem to a regular SQL lookup would be to serialize the rules to a string that can be used as a key. The value will the result. For eg.
{ 
  "x,y,z": "z",
   "t,x,y": "t"
}

Now, this handles cases for an exact ruleset matching to one. 

In other cases, you can have different strategies and different tables for the rules as well.
So, you can evaluate all the rules with their associated relations and return as soon as you find one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a property file, where you can store the rules in a key vale pair and read the property file and apply that rule in the code instead of using case or switch statements, so you don't have to hard code anything.
Other approach would be to store the rules in a table and do a lookup on the table. If the rules are minimum, I recommend the property/config file approach so you can avoid the round trip DB call.